# In Python: Search for two words in multiple texts using raw_input

Tags: python, macos

I want to open (raw_input) multiple text files in a directory, give them a name (Document 1, Document 2...), search (raw_input) for two words using "OR" and then put the search word (without characters ".,/"" only the words in lower case) and names of the files containing the word/words in a list or new text file:

I've tried to put the files into a dictionary, but I don't really know if that is a stupid idea?

I don't know how to let the user search for one or two words (via raw_input) in all the files at the same time. Can you help me or give me a hint?

I want it to print something like:

> > > SearchWord "found in " Document 1, python.txt
> > >       SearchWord "found in " Document 3, foobar.txt

```
import re, os


path = raw_input("insert path to directory :")
ex_library = os.listdir(path)
search_words = open("sword.txt", "w") # File or maybe list to put in the results
thelist = []

for texts in ex_library:
    file = os.path.join(path, texts)
    text = open(file, "r")
    textname = os.path.basename(texts)
    print textname
    for names in textname.split():
        thelist.append(names)
    text.close()
print thelist


print "These texts are now open"
print "###########################"

count = 0
for y in ex_library:
    count = count + 1
print count
print "texts total"

d ={}


for x in range(count):
    d["Document {0}".format(x)] = None # I would like the values to be the names of the texts (text1.txt)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Two glaring issues with the code- first, you could just use `count = `len(ex_library)` rather than use a for loop. Second, there's no reason to use dictionaries like this: `d["Document {0}".format(x)]`: that's just a list. The point of a dictionary is to allow mapping from keys to values- for example, from a file name to a list of words in the file.

Comment: And why print them to the user as Document 1, Document 2, etc- that doesn't mean anything to the user.

Comment: This question is also a bit confusing since you're opening up data files but not doing anything with them (other than closing them again). All you're doing is manipulating the file name. Do you need help figuring out how to read the data file and search for a keyword?

Comment: Yes, please. I don't know how to let the user search for one or two words (via raw_input) in all the files at the same time.